# THREE.js: Display Photograph - don't stretch the texture

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to display a photograph in my THREE.js scene. The size of the geometry is based on on the window and the photograph, which added as Texture should cover the geometry. Basically what I want is `background-size: cover` in CSS, but in THREE.js, so that I can add some more transformations to this geometry.

This is my code so far:

```
const txture = this.loader.load('/site/themes/pride/img/home_1.jpg');
const material = new MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: txture,
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 1,
});
const geom = new BoxBufferGeometry( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, 0.0001 );
const plane = new Mesh(geom, material);
plane.overdraw = true;
plane.position.set(0,0,0);
```

Is this even possible or should I do it in a complete other way?

Comment: which version of Three.js do you use?

Comment: @ArtyomAmiryan 100

Comment: is your `this.loader` instance of `new THREE.TextureLoader()` ?

Comment: @ArtyomAmiryan Yes, sorry!

Comment: I guess you are need UV map for your texture